# Rigidbody falling speed resets when moving midair

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

So my rigidbody controller has a speed limiter with the following code:

```
 Vector3 flatVel = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);
 // limit velocity if needed
 if (flatVel.magnitude > moveSpeed)
 {
  Vector3 limitedVel = flatVel.normalized * moveSpeed;
  rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);
 }
```

but for some reason that last line of code:

`rb.velocity = new Vector3(limitedVel.x, rb.velocity.y, limitedVel.z);`

causes my character's falling speed to reset when moving in midair, when it reaches about -50 units of speed. I've tried modifiying `rb.velocity.x` and `rb.velocity.z` seperately, but Unity doesn't allow that. Is there any other way to cap rigidbody speeds without using rb.velocity?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Unity documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

**In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly, as this can result in unrealistic behaviour - use AddForce instead Do not set the velocity of an object every physics step, this will lead to unrealistic physics simulation. A typical usage is where you would change the velocity is when jumping in a first person shooter, because you want an immediate change in velocity.**

I'd say this is the reason you are encountering the behaviour that you are.

A Unity forum post, found [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/9985/limiting-rigidbody-velocity.html), suggests the correct way to do this is:

**The 'proper' way would be to apply a force in the opposite direction of the rigidbody's velocity. The amount of force should be proportional to the extent to which the rigidbody is exceeding its speed limit.**

Another Unity forum post suggests to make use of the `ClampMagnitude` method, the post can be found [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/problem-clamping-rigidbody-velocity.580054/).

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var force = new Vector3(input.x, 0f, input.y) * acceleration;
    var velocity = playerRigidbody.velocity + force;
    playerRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);
}
```

Hope this helps.